# WebOS app not scrolling down on the main page

Tags: scroll, webos, enyo

I have an Enyo webOS application I am developing for phones.  There are several text inputs on the main page, with a button underneath them--however, the button is not viewable below the textboxes.  However, there appears to be a scroll lock by default on the main scene--so I cannot scroll down and see the rest of the content.

How can I enable my app to allow for scrolling within a VFlexBox view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I found it--I need to change from enyo.VFlexBox to enyo.Scroller for the view.  Works fine!